# Dynamic CheckedTextview

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have dynamic CheckedTextview in my_xml;

my_xml:

```
 <CheckedTextView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/text1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
   android:paddingLeft="8dip"
   android:paddingRight="8dip"
 />
```

in this i have set adapter like this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listvalues);
```

i want how to find if checkedtextview is checked or unchecked?

Comment: you can use isChecked() method on object of it

Comment: When do you want to know it? Please give a little bit more context. Otherwise just call `isChecked()` on the CheckedTextView.

Comment: in this xml file is default in android named as android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice...then how can i take this id and use isChecked() ??

Comment: i dont what you want to achieve.. as per layout you use you can check multiple items. you can use clicklistener per item checked

Comment: i cant understand?can u please explain?